# Total row of my table : how to not Display my indicator?

Tags: powerbi, dax, data-analysis, powerbi-desktop, measure

_Hi, I have some trouble to not display my red indicator on the total of my "Negative consumption" table when it has only one row... Can anyone help me ? Thanks in advance.
[Here is the link of my pbix file](https://1drv.ms/u/s!An2aQoxg76Kv8Vi8_m9NCXztsGNZ?e=RgtcxC)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use ISINSCOPE() instead.

```
Count conso NEG LR = // Calcul du nombre de fois, par BAT, où la conso est négative

VAR _NB_Conso_Neg =
CALCULATE(
    COUNT('BDD Index'[Conso]),
    'BDD Index'[Conso] < 0 && 'BDD Index'[Bat] = SELECTEDVALUE(BAT[BAT]) && 'BDD Index'[Ordre TimeLine] = MAX('BDD Index'[Ordre TimeLine])
)

RETURN
SWITCH(
    TRUE(),
    ISBLANK(_NB_Conso_Neg) && ISINSCOPE('Plans Comptages'[CPTc]), "",
    NOT ISBLANK(_NB_Conso_Neg) && ISINSCOPE('Plans Comptages'[CPTc]),"",
    ""
)
```

Comment: Wonderfull Davide! I always learn a lot with your answers... A Thousand Thanks